# How to check minimum and max times with LocalDateTime java ie minimum 10:00 and max time 10:30

Tags: java, time, datetime-comparison

I am new to java and I am having a problem with checking if a time falls/fits into a space of time, ie 10:00-10:30.

The idea is to find out if the time is between 10:00 and 10:30

below is my code:

```
LocalDateTime timecheck = LocalDate.now().atTime(10, 29);

if(timecheck.getHour() == 10 &&(timecheck.getMinute() <= 30 && timecheck.getMinute() >= 0))
{
      //do something
}
```

Is there is a way to do this simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only want to check the time, you don't have to use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`. The `LocalTime` class is sufficient.

You can use `LocalTime.isBefore()` and `LocalTime.isAfter()`:

```
LocalTime timecheck = LocalTime.of(10, 29);
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(10, 0);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(10, 30);

if (!start.isAfter(timecheck) && !end.isBefore(timecheck)) {
    ...
}
```

Note that this also includes 10:00 and 10:30.

Comment: Thanks a lot that simplified my logic